# Swift: How to better format the output when using println with a tuple?

Tags: swift, tuples, xcode6-beta5

I have defined this function:

```
func need_rebalance() -> (Bool, RebalanceStrategy) {

}
```

where RebalanceStrategy is an enum type

```
enum RebalanceStrategy: String {
    case LeftRight = "LeftRight"
    case RightLeft = "RightLeft"
}
```

When I tried to print it this way,

```
    println("Need rebalance? \(self.need_rebalance())")
```

I got output like this:

```
Need rebalance? (false, (Enum Value))
```

My questions are:

1) Is there an easy to extract a value from a tuple? (Hopefully something similar to python e.g. self.need_rebalance()[1]. Apparently this syntax does not work in swift because tuple does not support `subscript()`)

2) How can I print the raw value of enum instead of having `(Enum Value)`?

I am using XCode6 Beta5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a way to extract the value using tuple indexes, but it's not nice, it involves `reflect`:

```
let tuple = self.need_rebalance()
let reflection = reflect(tuple)
reflection[0].1.value // -> true
reflection[1].1.value // -> RebalanceStrategy.?
```

Also, if your tuple members are not named:

```
let tuple = self.need_rebalance()
tuple.0 // -> true
tuple.1 // -> RebalanceStrategy.?
```

To access the raw value in an `enum`:

```
RebalanceStrategy.LeftRight.toRaw()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.0`, `.1` and so on to get the respective value from an unnamed tuple.

To get the raw value of the enum, use `.toRaw()`

```
var tuple = self.need_rebalance()

println("Need rebalance? \(tuple.0),\(tuple.1.toRaw())")
```

---

Better still, use a named tuple like this:

```
var tuple : (boolValue : Bool, enumValue :RebalanceStrategy) = self.need_rebalance()

println("Need rebalance? \(tuple.boolValue),\(tuple.enumValue.toRaw())")
```